# Python generator initialize- 2 ways ,different outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am using python 3.3.3. i am learning generator and as far as I have gone, I have learnt two ways to initialize a generator.

1. using generator comprehension

   ```
   gen1 = (i * i for i in range(6))
   ```
2. using function and yield

   ```
   def fib():
       a,b=0,1
       while True:
           yield a
           a,b=b,a+b
   gen2=fib()
   ```

now when i use next(gen1) again and again, i get 0,1,4,9,... as output.
but when i use next(fib()) again and again, i get 0, 0 ,0,0 as output. i was thinking the output should be instead 0,1,1,2,3,5,....

```
print(next(fib())
print(next(fib())
print(next(fib())
print(next(fib())
```

is the code that prints 0,0,0,0

Comment: please show the code which prints 0,0,0,...

Comment: `next(gen2)` works as expected. See [this ideone](http://ideone.com/1yGWQT).

Comment: Are you calling `next(fib())` repeatedly? If so, that's a bug; you need to call `fib()` once and then `next` the return value repeatedly.

Comment: @falsetru i know where i was wrong. thanks for the help

Comment: @user2357112 yes sir, that is what i am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def fib():
...     a,b=0,1
...     while True:
...         yield a
...         a,b=b,a+b
... 
>>> next(fib())
0
>>> next(fib())
0
>>> gen = fib()
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
>>>
```

When you do `next(fib())` you are creating the generator from scratch each time.

Answer (score 0):

The following program prints fibonacci numbers neatly in Python 3.3.3 Can you show me your full program?

```
def fib():
    a,b=0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b=b,a+b
gen2=fib()

for i in gen2:
    print(i)
    if i > 100: #otherwise this will go into an infinite loop
        break
```

Prints out

```
0
1
1
2
3
..
144
```

Comment: i don't want to use for loop. i want to do using next(). i know for loop is the easier approach but i am in learning phase and would like to use next()

Comment: @hoder you can simply keep printing next(gen2). The for loop is only for a demonstration. I have now changed it to use for loop directly on the "gen2" generator. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But this does not work.                                           `def fib():
    a,b=0,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b=b,a+b
gen2=fib()

for i in range(5):
    print(next(fib()))
`Sorry, i don't know how to format my comment

Comment: @hoder your problem is doing next(fib()). That is wrong you must say gen2=fib() and call next(gen2). It is important to not have paranthesis in the next call. Otherwise you are simply "re-initialising" the generator over and over again, which is why you always start from 0 :)